# How to proxy upstream servers in order, and with a limit?

Tags: nginx

I am proxying a directory to a `websocket` upstream:

```
        location /Fonzy {
                        proxy_pass http://websocket;
                        proxy_http_version 1.1;
                        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            }
```

upstream:

```
upstream websocket {
    least_conn; 
    server 127.0.0.1:9300;
    server 127.0.0.1:9301;
    server 127.0.0.1:9302;
}
```

`least_conn` will proxy to the server which has the least amount of connections.

My problem is I am trying to proxy lets say ***200*** connections to `9300` and then once 200 connections have been fulfilled, the next 200 will go to `9301`, and so on.

I found the `max_conns` [property](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#max_conns), but this is for the commercial version. However, I'm not even sure if that is a solution.

Comment: Weird. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to get the servers in my upstream to sequentially receive a maximum of 200 connections from top to down (in order)

Comment: Could people who down vote please explain why they're doing so? To me, this question is neither "unclear" nor "doesn't it show any research efforts".  One could ask what's the intention of this, as @kubanczyk did, but besides this I don't see any problem with this question. If people got a different impression, please raise your voice!